# Laravel: In a Blade file, is there a way to wait for response from form submission before allowing another click?

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-blade

I have a Blade file that has a form submission to `add to cart`. It seems users are getting the item added to the cart multiple times.  When I click the submit button, the `data-loading-text` is changing to "Adding..." and it seems to be, from my testing, that it does not hit the API again regardless of how fast I hammer click the button.  But somehow, customers are saying it is adding to the cart numerous times so is there a way to disable the button until a form response from the backend comes back?

```
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     <button type="submit" data-loading-text="Adding..." class="btn btn-success">Add Quantity</button>
```

Comment: Could you also share your Javascript? Very simple solution would be adding the `disabled` property to the button once the request is being executed.

Comment: via an `onclick`?  The blade file has no JS in it at all.  The form submission is a basic `type=submit` in the button because there is an action route defined in the form tag so it's all done on the backend

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your js file, just implement `onsubmit` event, disable the button in it and then enable the button when response comes.

Comment: I'm not using AJAX though.  The response is received on the backend.  The form tag has an action defined so the button just has `type=submit`

Comment: You can still disable the button. This way it can only be clicked once until the page reloads.